Zsh: partial colouring in completion, preserving `LS_COLORS` in unmatched part
In Bash, with the following settings in ~/.inputrc:
set colored-completion-prefix on
set colored-stats on
set mark-symlinked-directories on
set visible-stats on

and so=01;90:ln=04;94:di=01;96 present somewhere in LS_COLORS, I can get completions as seen below.

Note that the matched part of each item in the completion list is coloured grey (because of so=01;90 in LS_COLORS), but the unmatched part is written in the normal colour defined in LS_COLORS (as set by ln=04;94 and di=01;96).
In Zsh, with the following (from this Stack Overflow answer) in ~/.zshrc,
zstyle -e ':completion:*:default' list-colors 'reply=("${PREFIX:+=(#bi)($PREFIX:t)(?)*==1;90=}:${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}")'

I get this.

Which is wildly inconsistent! (The first and third completions appear to not have followed the style defined.) How do I get Zsh to colour completions the Bash way? Having read the relevant section 22.7 of the Zsh manual, I understand that the unmatched part is coloured white because the style tells it to (in *==1;90=), but want it to use the 'default' colour from LS_COLORS, depending on item type. Like Bash does.

I don't think there is a way to emulate Bash-style completion colouring. The closest I could get to it is with
zstyle -e ':completion:*:default' list-colors 'BASE_OF_PREFIX=${PREFIX##*/} && reply=("${BASE_OF_PREFIX:+=(#b)($BASE_OF_PREFIX)(*)=0=1;90=0}:$LS_COLORS")'

which formats completion words as follows.

The only difference between this and what I wanted is that the unmatched part of a completion word (i.e. 32 in lib32 and 64@ in lib64@) is shown in the normal colour (white) instead of the colour it would been shown in when displayed using ls (bold cyan and underlined blue, respectively).
Why didn't this suggested solution work?
zstyle -e ':completion:*:default' list-colors 'reply=("${PREFIX:+=(#bi)($PREFIX:t)(?)*==1;90=}:${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}")'

This tells Zsh to obtain the base name ($PREFIX:t) of the text just before the cursor ($PREFIX), and colour it grey if it appears at the start of completion word ((#bi)($PREFIX:t)) and has at least one character following it ((?)*). Let's say $PREFIX is /usr/lib, so $PREFIX:t is lib. lib does not match the pattern ($PREFIX:t)(?)* (i.e. 'lib followed by at least one character'), so lib in the list of completion words is not coloured grey (as seen in the second image in the question).
Another problem with this solution is that the base name obtained this way is not what we'd want while colouring completions. If $PREFIX is /usr/, then $PREFIX:t will be usr, which would mean Zsh would try to colour usr grey in the list of completion words, which is wrong: we have already entered usr and want to colour nothing grey, because we have typed nothing after the last slash in /usr/.
Why does this solution work?
zstyle -e ':completion:*:default' list-colors 'BASE_OF_PREFIX=${PREFIX##*/} && reply=("${BASE_OF_PREFIX:+=(#b)($BASE_OF_PREFIX)(*)=0=1;90=0}:$LS_COLORS")'

It does two things differently.

Obtains the base name using parameter expansion (BASE_OF_PREFIX=${PREFIX##*/}), so that the base name of /usr/ is the empty string.
Matches the base name if it appears at the start of a completion word (($BASE_OF_PREFIX)(*)) without requiring any more characters after it.

Using the same example as above, Let's say $PREFIX is /usr/lib, so $BASE_OF_PREFIX is lib. lib matches the pattern ($BASE_OF_PREFIX)(*) (i.e. 'lib followed by any number of characters'), so lib in the list of completion words is coloured grey (as seen in the image in this answer).
Are there any situations where this will not work?
Yes. Trying to complete chsh -s displays the full paths to the shells available on the system rather than just the part of the path immediately after the last slash typed. For instance, if you type chsh -s /usr/bin/ and press Tab, the suggested completions words aren't the shell binaries, but the full paths to them, which this solution doesn't handle. Nothing will be coloured grey. Similarly, completing some options will also produce completion words not coloured grey.
This is could be one those things in which Bash beats Zsh fair and square.
